# Trouble during phpUnderContol installation on Mac OS

Tags: php, macos, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol, phpundercontrol

I have downloaded last release of CruiseControl and phpUnderControl now I need to "connect them" how its given here http://phpundercontrol.org/documentation/installation.html

But When I enter

```
phpUnderControl/bin/phpuc(.php|.bat) install /path/to/cruisecontrol
```

I receive this answer from my terminal -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `.php'

Have you any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.bat is only required on Windows. You should use something like this:

```
phpUnderControl/bin/phpuc.php install /path/to/cruisecontrol
```